# mongoose index don't create

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I tried to create index from two fields in mongoose Schema but it didn't work
this two fields are the id of two other schema and i want to be unique
i get the ids from "mongoose.Schema.ObjectId"

this is my code:

```
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        review: {
            type: String,
            required: [ true, 'Review can not be empty!' ],
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        },
        tour: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Tour',
            required: [ true, 'Review must belong to a tour.' ],
        },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: [ true, 'Review must belong to a user' ],
        },
    },
    {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
    },
);

reviewSchema.index({ tour: 1, user: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Comment: This is indeed the way to create such a compound index. How did you confirm the index wasn't created? Did you try to get the list of indexes via the `mongo shell`?

Comment: yes. my database is on atlas and my mongoDB Compass is connect to atlas, i can see the indexes. i create index in another schema but in this schema it didn't work

Comment: Because you provided the most minimal code you could, I'd reckon on creating a testing collection, with two fields (excluding `_id`), and create a compound index, without providing `options` object in schema creation (your `toObject, toJSON` stuff). Of course create a separate file in your same project system.

Comment: As additional note, you don't have to provide `createdAt` field in your schema - you could provide in `options` object: `timestamps: true` and it will create you automatically `created_at, updated_at` fields.

Comment: i know, its just a test and i found the problem it was a bug from atlas .

Answer (score 0):

I found it was a bug from atlas ,I don't know why but it couldnt create index with options
I create a local data base and now it works